# Allure reports. Is there a way of specifying a port for publishing reports using serve command?

Tags: allure

Every time I use the serve command, the server starts up on different port. For example, http://10.25.11.184:57818/ or http://10.25.11.184:64540/
I'd like to configure it using maven so that the port is always the same. I've searched through Allure documentation and can't find a way to do this. 
Would be really grateful for some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Allure serve has option `-p` or `--port` to specify the port.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your desired port number as below -
allure serve C:\YourTestProject\reports\allure-results --port 9999